# Stirling number proof, proving that $s(n, n-2) = 2{n\choose3} + 3{n\choose4}$

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

Let $s(n,k)$ denote the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind. Prove that
$$s(n, n-2) = {n\choose3} + 3{n\choose4} $$

-I had a similar question for the $s(n, n-1)$ case, but unsure of how to solve for this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** The formula in the question is wrong: the righthand side should be $2\binom{n}3+3\binom{n}4$.

HINT: Suppose that a permutation of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ has $n-2$ cycles. There are two possibilities.

- It might have a $3$-cycle; how many such permutations are there?
- If it does not have a $3$-cycle, what must it look like? How many of *those* permutations are there?

Comment: So it can either have a 3 cycle or two 2 cycles right? As for how many of each I'm not really sure how to figure that out.

Comment: @jeremysanchez50: You’ve correctly identified the two types. How many ways are there to choose $3$ elements for a $3$-cycle, and once you have them, how many different $3$-cycles can you make? To make two $2$-cycles, you can pick $4$ things and then split them into two pairs.

Comment: why do we have $2$ times $n \choose 3$? there seems to be only one way to organize the three elements . and not 2.

Comment: I also agree that $\binom{n}{3}$ should have coefficient $1$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178691/partition-n-elements-into-n-2-boxes-find-sn-n-2-for-all-n-geq-2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: maybe a bit late, but @Mahidevran and, if you have a 3 cycle then you have (x1, x2, x3) AND (x1, x3, x2) with x1!=x2!=x3, so you have to have 2 * (n over 3)

Comment: @Muno: That is a different question: it deals with Stirling numbers of the **second** kind, while this one deals with Stirling numbers of the **first** kind. For this question the order matters: the permutation $(123)$ is different from the permutation $(132)$.