# Partition $n$ elements into $n-2$ boxes. Find $S(n,n-2)$ for all $n \geq 2$.

Tags: combinatorics

Find a close formula for $S(n,n-2)$ for all $n \geq 2$.

attempt: We need to partition $[n] = {\{1,...,n-1,n}\}$ into $n-2$ indistinguishable boxes.
So suppose we have two cases.
The first case, there are 3 elements in any of the $n-2$ boxes.  So we would choose $3$ elements out of the $n$ elements. So $n \choose 3$ choices.

Second case: We have 2 boxes with 2 elements in any of the $n-2$ boxes and the remaining $n-4$ boxes , they have $1$ element each. Then we have $n \choose 2$ if we pick $2$ elements out of the $n$ that are there, and we ar left with ${\{1,2,....,n-3 ,n-2}\}$ elements to choose from. And $n-3$ boxes. So we pick $ n-3 \choose 2$ . Thus, multiplying these options, we have $ n-3 \choose 2$ $n \choose 2$.

Thus combining these two cases, we have $n \choose 3$ +  $ n-3 \choose 2$ $n \choose 2$.

Can someone please verify this? especially the second case. And any feedback will be appreciated it. Thank you.

Comment: Does your answer check out when $n-4?\ n=5?\ n=7?$

Comment: I get $3\binom n4+\binom n3.$

Comment: So the first case is fine. So the second case is wrong for me

Comment: we are choosing $2$ elements from a box and there are $n$ elements , so $n \choose 2$, then there are $n-3$ remaining boxes , and $n-2$ elements. This is how I understand it. I don't quite see how you got $3 $ $n \choose 4$.

Comment: Where does your $\binom{n-3}2$ come from? You have $n-2$ elements and $n-3$ boxes. So you are choosing $2$ ***boxes***? But the boxes are all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First case:** Pick the $3$ elements which share a box; $\binom n3$ ways to do that.

**Second case:** Pick the $4$ elements which do not get private boxes; $\binom n4$ ways to do that.Then divide the chosen $4$ elements into two groups of two: $3$ ways to do that.

**Final answer:** $S(n,n-2)=\binom n3+3\binom n4.$

**Example:** $S(4,2)=\binom43+3\binom44=3+4=7.$ If the four elements are $a,b,c,d,$ then the $7$ partitions are $abc|d,\ abd|c,\ acd|b,\ bcd|a$ and $ab|cd,\ ac|bd,\ ad|bc.$

**Example:** $S(5,3)=\binom53+3\binom54=10+15=25.$ The $25$ partitions are $abc|d|e,\ abd|c|e,\ abe|c|d,\ acd|b|e,\ ace|b|d,\ ade|b|c,\ bcd|a|e,\ bce|a|d,\ bde|a|c,\ cde|a|b$ and $a|bc|de,\ a|bd|ce,\ a|be|cd,\ b|ac|de,\ b|ad|ce,\ b|ae|cd,\ c|ab|de,\ c|ad|be,\ c|ae|bd,\ d|ab|ce,\ d|ac|be,\ d|ae|bc,\ e|ab|cd,\ e|ac|bd,\ e|ad|bc.$

Comment: An element gets a "private box" if it's the only element in its box. This is not official terminology but I thought it might be self-explanatory.

Comment: I don't quite see why there are 3 ways to do that. Assume we have the elements as balls. Do you refer to if we pick ball $1 ,2,3,4$ balls , then the can partition the 4 balls into the two boxes  as 1 option as  $1, 2$ and $3,4$ ?Similarly 2 case ) $1,3$ and $2,4$. Similarly case 3) we have $1,4$ and $3,2$?  So three ways?

Comment: Yes, I meant $S(5,3),$ thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yes, three ways to partition a $4$-element set into two $2$-element sets. If the elements are A,B,C,D, there are $3$ ways to choose a "cellmate" for A, and then the remaining two elements have no choice. Also, you can think of it as $\binom42/2.$

Comment: In the first case, you pick $3$ elements and put them all in one box. Where do you get a factor of $2?$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517802/stirling-number-proof-proving-that-sn-n-2-2n-choose3-3n-choose4?rq=1

Comment: user bof. The above link  seems to be the same problem. However, I don't understand why it has a $2$ on the $n \choose 3$. After thinking about it, it seems there is only one way to organize the three balls we choose in a box.  And so $n \choose 3$ makes sense as you defined it.  and not multiplied by 2. Can you please verify this?

Comment: It's not the same problem; $s(n,k)$ with a small "s" is a Stirling number of the ***first kind***. Your problem is about Stirling numbers of the ***second kind***. See the Wikipedia article on [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number).