# Show that $S(n, n-2) = {n\choose3} + 3{n\choose4}$

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

Where $S(n,k)$ is the stirling number of the second kind.

In my combinatorics course $S(n,k)$ has only been defined as the "number of ways to put $n$ distinguishable balls in $k$ non-distinguishable cells that cannot be empty".

I know the correct answer is $S(n, n-2) = {n\choose3} + 3{n\choose4}$ (from [Stirling number proof, proving that $s(n, n-2) = 2{n\choose3} + 3{n\choose4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517802/stirling-number-proof-proving-that-sn-n-2-2n-choose3-3n-choose4)) but have no clue how to start the problem. I feel that the hint in the link I just gave did not help me. Would anyone have any other help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such an arrangement would be of two possible types: (i) $3$ balls in one box, with the remaining $n-3$ boxes with one ball apiece, (ii)
$2$ balls in one box, $2$ in another box, and $n-4$ boxes with one ball apiece.

To count the type (i) arrangements, all you have to do is specify the
$3$ balls that go together. There are $\binom n3$ ways to do this.
For type (ii), there are $\binom n4$ ways to choose the non-lonely balls,
but then what?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $S(n,n-2)$ denotes the number of ways to partition a set with $n$ elements into $n-2$ non-empty blocks.

First, make $n-2$ blocks and put $1$ element in each block, so that no block is empty. We are left with $2$ elements. These $2$ elements can either be both put into one block, or they can be put in separate blocks. We hence have the following two cases:

**Case $1$:** If the $2$ elements are both put in the same block, then we essentially have $3$ elements in one block and the remaining $n-3$ blocks contain $1$ element each. Note that order in which the blocks are placed does not matter in counting the set partitions (in some sense, the blocks are identical). Thus, there are $n\choose3$ ways to choose which $3$ elements will together make one block.

**Case $2$:** If the $2$ elements are placed in different blocks, then two blocks out of $n-2$ contains $2$ elements each, and the remaining $n-4$ blocks will contain $1$ element each. There are $n\choose4$ ways to select the $4$ elements that will be shared between $2$ blocks, and these $4$ chosen elements can be divided into two blocks of size two each in $3$ ways.

For example, if $\{a,b,c,d\}$ are chosen, then the following combinations will give rise to different partitions:

$$\{a,b\},\{c,d\}
\\ \{a,c\},\{b,d\} \\ \{a,d\},\{b,c\}$$
So, from this case arises $3$$n\choose4$ partitions.

Hence, $S(n,n-2) =$ $n\choose3$ $+ 3$$n\choose4$ $\blacksquare$